# How to set auto start brightcove video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

Hi i am used brightcove video my html page light box pop up. click image successfully popup brightcove video. my query is click thumbnail image image popup and auto play brightcove video.thanks for your feature help.

```
Script:
    $(".thumb3").on('click',function()
        {
        var $p3 = $("#videos3");
        $(".thumb3").colorbox({
              inline: true, 
              width: "45%",
              href: $p3
        });
    });

    code:
    <div class="leader_videos">
        <a class='thumb3' href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="images/video-3.jpg"></a> 
            <div class="videos">
                 <div  id="videos3">
        <object id="myExperience3884695242001" class="BrightcoveExperience" autoStart="true"> 
<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" /> 
<param name="width" value="100%" /> 
<param name="height" value="350" /> 
<param name="playerID" value="645226206001" /> 
<param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAAAlj15pkk~,3Csx1C7ZFcLlAwiBFL1XG62fIVDuXW7R" />
<param name="autoplay" value="false" />
<param name="autostart" value="0" /> 
<param name="isVid" value="true" /> 
<param name="isUI" value="true" /> 
<param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
<param name="@videoPlayer" value="3884695242001" /> 
</object>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: my question is brightcove video auto play light box popup.

Comment: i am already use this code

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<param name="autoplay" value="false" id="autoplay-lightbox"/>
```

And in your JQuery code (I don't know if it is working):

```
   $("#autoplay-lightbox").attr( "value", "true" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you grab the experience id from the video.

```
var vid = document.getElementById('expirienceIdGoesHere');
var dataString = vid.data;
dataString = dataString.replace('autoStart=false','autoStart=true');
vid.data = dataString;
```

and set this on your popup click function